# Does Guava ImmutableMap postpone Map resize?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

While I am testing the Guava ImmutableMap and HashMap, I found ImmutableMap resize not at regular point, aka, 16, 32, 64. What does this mean?

Test code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mapFootPrint = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i ++){
    mapFootPrint.put(i, i+ 128); //no cache integer
    ImmutableMap<Integer, Integer> immutableMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(mapFootPrint);

    System.out.println(MemoryMeasurer.measureBytes(mapFootPrint));
    System.out.println(MemoryMeasurer.measureBytes(immutableMap));
}
```

Result graph:
[image]

Y-axis is memory footprint in bytes, and X-axis is map size. Blue is HashMap and Orange is ImmutableMap. You can see ImmutableMap resize later than HashMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a different load factor - 1.33 for normal `HashMap` and 1.2 for `ImmutableMap`. All hash maps have free space as hashing is never perfect, mutable maps need additional space for potential new entries. Look at Guava `com.google.common.collect.Hashing.closedTableSize()`, Guava `com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.MAX_LOAD_FACTOR`, and `java.util.HashMap.DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR`.

Comment: Seems it is a load factor matter. but I am using Java 7 HotSpot 64-bit, and the `DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR` is 0.75f. Do you have any idea why Google chooses a different ratio? Any Benchmark?

Comment: It is a difference in a way the number is stored and applied - one library uses multiplication, other division: items*1.33 = items/(0.75), items*1.25 = items/(0.80)